# Excel: HLOOKUP() where blank cells are skipped

Tags: excel, concatenation

I am trying to create an HLOOKUP() style formula that, if it finds a matching heading where the reported value of the row it's on except if it is blank it skips it and looks for the next column with the same heading in the same row.

An example of the data table is as follows:

```
    Heading 1   Heading 2   Heading 1   Heading 4   Heading 5   Heading 1
Sample 1    1   7       13  19  
Sample 2        8       14  20  2
Sample 3        9       15  21  3
Sample 4    4   10      16  22  
Sample 5    5   11      17  23  
Sample 6        12  6   18  24
```

As you can see, the data under headings 2, 4 and 5 are all in single columns, but the heading 1 values are split between three columns.

I need the final data set to look like this:

```
    Heading 1   Heading 2   Heading 4   Heading 5
Sample 1    1   7   13  19
Sample 2    2   8   14  20
Sample 3    3   9   15  21
Sample 4    4   10  16  22
Sample 5    5   11  17  23
Sample 6    6   12  18  24
```

I have done some research online and have found a formula that I thought was meant to work as a VLOOKUP(), I can't quite work out what it's doing and when I try it on a transposed version of my data set it doesn't quite do what I expect. I Have been trying to get it work in and also convert it to work in the opposite orientation. The formula is as follows:

```
{=INDEX($B$3:$G$8,SMALL(IF(INDEX($A$3:$G$8,,MATCH(B$11,$B$2:$G$2,0))<>"",IF($A$3:$A$8=$A12,ROW($A$3:$G$8)-ROW($A3)+$I12)),1),MATCH(B$11,$B$2:$G$2,0))}
```

This formula is from https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/689238-vlookup-match-but-ignore-blank-cells.html

Running the formula on a transposed version of my data set results in the following:

```
**Transposed data set**                             
    Sample 1    Sample 2    Sample 3    Sample 4    Sample 5    Sample 6        
Heading 1   1           4   5           
Heading 2   7   8   9   10  11  12      
Heading 1                       6       
Heading 4   13  14  15  16  17  18      
Heading 5   19  20  21  22  23  24      
Heading 1       2   3                   

**Result**                              
    Sample 1    Sample 2    Sample 3    Sample 4    Sample 5    Sample 6        
Heading 1   1   0   3   0   5   0       1
Heading 2   7   8   9   10  11  12      2
Heading 4   13  14  15  16  17  18      3
Heading 5   19  20  21  22  23  24      4

**Expected result**                             
    Sample 1    Sample 2    Sample 3    Sample 4    Sample 5    Sample 6        
Heading 1   1   2   3   4   5   6       
Heading 2   7   8   9   10  11  12      
Heading 4   13  14  15  16  17  18      
Heading 5   19  20  21  22  23  24
```

I think that I am probably over complicating this and that there must be a simpler solution to the problem. Any help that anyone can give me would be great. Let me

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is maybe faaar to simple, but why don't you simply add the values of the ´Heading 1´ columns? The empty values are treated as value 0, and by the end you'll have the values you are looking for :-)

Comment: Simple is what was needed!! I can't believe I missed it. Thanks so much for your help!